# unable to control display brightness Gateway laptop

Tags: display

I have install the Ubuntu on my Gateway laptop. Everything works fine except that I cant control my display brightness. When i press the control I can see the cursor moving from low to high but it didn't apply those changes to my screen[.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hSGbq.jpg)

Comment: I had a similar behavior of my notebook (Acer), the brightness was always set to maximum, after a certain time with an ubuntu update the problem disappeared.

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: Now I have 20.04. but it was earlier.

Comment: I have version 20.04. The only i can change it is with the command prompt. Kind of annoying.